# How to check arguments passed to the function call are empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want the function to simply check if an argument is passed or not. If not, print something, else say some hello and that argument.

Here is sample of my code:

```
def say_name(name):
  if name is None:
    print("Hello there")
  else:
    print("Hello, "+ name + "!")
```

run code:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_should_say_hello(self):
    self.assertEqual(say_name("Michael"), "Hello, Michael!")
```

I have tried using `None`, Kwargs and still not working. **How can I check whether argument is passed to the function?**

Comment: Your current code won't work if there is no parameter passed, the argument isn't optional.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, the test will never succeed.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between returning a value and printing.

Comment: You might also want to consider the case that an empty string is passed as an argument. `"" is not None`, but it also doesn't contain any characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a parameter optional assign it a default value:

```
def say_name(name=None):
    if name is None:
        print("Hello there")
    else:
        print("Hello, "+ name + "!")
```

**Addendum:** As Barmar pointed out in the comments to your question, your function needs to [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) a string to make your check work.

```
def say_name(name=None):
    if name is None:
        return "Hello there"
    else:
        return "Hello, "+ name + "!"
```

Answer (score 3):

**To check whether "any" of the argument is passed with the function call**

In general, in order to check whether any argument is passed or not, you may create your function using `*args` *(for non-keyworded variable length argument list)* and `**kwargs` *(for keyworded variable length argument list)*. For example:

```
def check_argument(*args, **kwargs):
    if args or kwargs:   # check if any among the `args` or `kwargs` is present
        return "Argument Passed!"
    else:
        return "Argument Not passed!"
```

Sample Run:

```
# For "non-keyworded" argument
>>> check_argument('something')
'Argument Passed!'

# For "keyworded" argument
>>> check_argument(some_param='some_value')
'Argument Passed!'

# For no argumenet    
>>> check_argument()
'Argument Not passed!'
```

**To check if any "specific" argument is passed with the function call**

For your scenario, since you only care about one specific parameter `name` and perform operation based on the value passed, you may assign a `default` value to it's function definition as:

```
#                  v Default value as `None`
def say_name(name=None):
    if name is None:
        return "Hello, there!"
    else:
        return "Hello, "+ name + "!"
```

Above function could be simplified as:

```
#                    v setting default name as "there"
def say_name(name="there"):
    return "Hello, {}!".format(name)

# Or you may also check it within the format as
def say_name(name=None):
    return "Hello, {}!".format(name or "there")
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> say_name()
Hello, there!
>>> say_name('StackOverflow')
Hello, StackOverflow!
```

Answer (score 1):

def say_hello(*name):

```
if name:
  return "Hello, "+name[0]+"!"
else:
  return "Hello there!"
```

This should work